# Intel Realsense: Time is out of Dual 32-bit range

Tags: raspbian, ros, realsense, raspberry-pi4

We are trying to get the Intel Realsense D435i to work on our Raspberry Pi with the Raspbian OS and ROS Melodic.

After we configured our Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and installed ROS Melodic on it, we installed the realsense-ros package on our Raspberry Pi. When we connect our Realsense camera to the Raspberry and run the following command:

$ roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch

We get the following error:
[error: Time is out of Dual 32-bit range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXXiW.png)

We get some ros topics from the camera but they don't publish any data. Also not all of the topics are displayed. When we plug the camera in to a pc it works fine.

We already googled it and tried the following:

- full clean and rebuild of catkin workspace
- update and upgrade of all ros packages
- delete ros_comm package

But non off the above worked for us.

Is there anybody who has any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you check if your system time is set correctly?

Comment: You could also try to build the realsense-ros by yourself. I've noticed these type of exception also due to some version conflicts of the rostime library.